# Deploying Flask Socket.io application with eventlet on Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I am using flask socket.io configured with eventlet on a flexible google appengine instance. According to the flask socket.io documentation: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ running `socketio.run(app)` will start a webserver if eventlet is installed.

I have a local react web app attempting to establish a WebSocket connection with this app engine instance. The web app uses socket.io and initially defaults to polling HTTP requests. These requests all timeout-- I'm unable to establish a web socket connection. I'm not sure what might be causing my issue, whether it is my app engine configuration or my flask socket.io setup.

Here is my initialization code for flask socket.io:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
socketio.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
..
..
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

Here is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: python

env: flex

entrypoint: python3 server.py

runtime_config: 
  python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

network:
  session_affinity: true
```

Here is the web app code attempting to set up the connection:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socketURL = "<app-engine-instance-url>:5000"
const socket = io.connect(socketURL)
```

Comment: You have several things you can do to troubleshoot this. Have you look at the logs from your Flask app? Try sending a request with curl or similar and see if the log shows it. That would tell you if the app is listening to requests or not.

Comment: Perhaps you can try deploying [this sample Websocket app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/websockets) and modifying it to suit your needs?

Comment: You need to check the [entrypoint option](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#application_startup). In your case it should look something like this `gunicorn -b :$PORT --worker-class eventler -w 1 server:app`. Don't forget to add gunicorn and eventlet as dependencies.